# Unable to control audio volume in BackTrack5 R2

Tags: audio, backtrack

I have Backtrack5 R2, one of the several problems I have is the audio works but I cannot control the volume, it is always the same and it's very annoying.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed following the next steps:

1.- Click on system -> preferences -> startup applications

2.- Add

3.- Name: "whatever you want"

Command: "/usr/bin/pulseaudio"

Comment: "whatever you want"

4.- Click save

5.- Log out

6.- Type "startx" again and hit enter

Everything should work fine.